# Connecting Identity 2.0 to My Table using collections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5, asp.net-identity

I am new to MVC and Identity but I am using the Default MVC Project using Identity 2.0 for my authentication.

It has its own Identity dbtable dbo.AspNetUsers and I haven't made any modifications to  ApplicationUser().

```
// Must be expressed in terms of our custom Role and other types:
public class ApplicationUser 
    : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, 
    ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // Add any custom User properties/code here
    }


    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
        GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager
            .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

I have my own Entity Framework Database first EDMX model created as well with its own UserName and UserID column and other information in it.

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Characters = new HashSet<Character>();
    }

    public string USERID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UserCreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I am connecting these up using the RegisterViewModel and in my [HttpPost]ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int userHandleAlreadyExist = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName.ToUpper() == model.Handle.ToUpper()).Count();

            if (userHandleAlreadyExist > 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(model.Handle, "UserName already taken.  Please choose another.");
                return View(model);
            }
            var aUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(aUser, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                User user = new User
                {
                    USERID = aUser.Id,
                    UserName = model.Handle,
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    UserCreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                };

                db.Users.Attach(User);
                db.Users.Add(User);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(aUser.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = aUser.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(aUser.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");  //todo Will need to update the href here to Site URL once Live.
                ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
                return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I was told I could possibly connect these in my Models like the `ICollection<Character> Characters` is done in Entity Framework.  Can anyone walk me through how that could/would be done.

Best I can figure there would need to be some stuff done in the { get; set; } in a buddy partial class for the entity framework class and to the ApplicationUser model for Identity to link them but not sure what would actually need to be done.

Comment: I guess ut wouldn't be a collection since its really a 1 for 1 relationship User.USERID guid = ApplicationUser.Id guid

Comment: I am starting to think it can't really be done at least through the solution and using statements in the two models.  Maybe through database contexts.   When i try adding the project reference to my EF data layer it says it can't add the reference becsuse it would cause a circular reference.